# SwiftUI Deciding the best viewModel to put logic

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, swiftui, swift5

I have a similar app to Instagram let's say. There is a view called `ItemView` which displays details about an Item. In this view there is a button to save the item for later. exactly like Instagram.

I have two view models. `ItemViewModel` for the ItemView and another called `UserViewModel`

```
class ItemViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var item: Item

    init(item: Item) {
        self.item = item
    }

    // here?
    func saveItem() {
        //
    }

}

class UserViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var savedItems: [SavedItem] = []
    @Published var item: Item

    init(item: Item) {
        self.item = item
    }

    // or here?
    func saveItem(item: Item) {
        //
    }

}
```

Array of all saved items, as they belong to the user are saved in the `UserViewModel`.

The question is does this functionality to `saveItem()` belong to the `ItemViewModel` because this button is in `ItemView` or it belongs to `UserViewModel` because this is specific to a user and a user can save items? In which viewModel fits this better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the savedItems belong to the user, its the user's responsibility to deal with that, so saveItem() belongs to UserViewModel.

Comment: what about checking if a particular item is saved or not? `isSaved()` does this also belong to `userviewmodel` since savedItems belong to the user or belongs to the itemViewModel ?

Comment: isSaved is a characterisct/attribute of the Item, so its Item's responsibility so it should belong the Item.

Comment: When you have this kind of doubt, make the question: WHO will execute the act? WHERE the act should be made? This clarifies a lot for me :)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me that an `Item` would have an `isSaved` property,  why does an item care if it is saved?  You just add the item to user's array of saved `Item`. Then you can have a function on the user `isSaved(item:)->Bool` that tells you whether a given item is saved by this user.